# snprintf yields EXC_BAD_ACCESS when compiled in Xcode with Guard Malloc

Tags: c, debugging, runtime-error, clang

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
  const char* const template = "value->%s = event.content;\n";
  const char* const param = "name";

  const int res_len = strlen(template) + strlen(param) - 1;
  char* ret = malloc(sizeof(res_len));
  snprintf(ret, res_len, template, param);
  puts(ret);
}
```

If I compile and run it with Xcode, standard settings, it works as expected. However, when I edit my Project Scheme and turn „Guard Malloc“ in Diagnostics on, execution stops at the `snprintf` line with an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

Originally, I had `sprintf` there and assumed my calculation was wrong and `sprintf` tries to write past the buffer. So I switched to `snprintf`, which should guard against that… except that I *still* get the error. So now I am a bit at loss. What is causing this error?

Comment: Should `malloc(sizeof(res_len))` be `malloc(res_len)`?

Comment: oh dear, did I actually miss that

Comment: Happens to the best of us.

Comment: So you want to post an answer and get your rep? :)

Comment: I suppose if you insist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`malloc(sizeof(res_len))` should be `malloc(res_len)`

Answer (score 1):

You could instead use `asprintf` (GNU extension, also available on BSD and OS X). It would simplify things and
less error prone.

```
  const char* const param = "name";
  char *ret = NULL;

  if (asprintf(&ret, "value->%s = event.content;\n", param) != -1) {
      puts(ret);
  } else {
      fprintf(stderr, "asprintf failed.\n");
  }
```

Comment: You mentioned Xcode. It's part of the standard C library on OS X, so unlikely to be an issue because it's not C standard (your choice, of course).

Comment: While I do use Xcode for coding, I eventually want the code to compile on other platforms (like Windows) too.